# Compute log likelihood of data after fitting the GLM?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, matlab

Please forgive my inexpertise in stats. I am playing around with a toy general linear model (GLM) with MATLAB [glmfit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/glmval.html).

```
X=[1;2;3;4];
y=[1.1;2.2;3.5;4.9];
[b, dev, stats] = glmfit(X, y);
```

How should I compute the log likelihood of the data? I want to do

```
y_fit = glmval(b, X, 'identity');
ll = nansum(log(normpdf(y, y_fit, sigma)));
```

But how to find `sigma`, the standard deviation of the Gaussian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to compute the maximized likelihood, one needs the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) of the error standard deviation. It can be computed from the GLM residuals, `stats.resid`:

```
sigma = sqrt(mean(stats.resid .^ 2));
```

Using `nansum` should not normally be necessary, `sum` should do. To avoid problems with [arithmetic underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow), it would be better though to work with the log-density of the normal distribution:

```
ll = sum(-0.5 * (stats.resid / sigma) .^ 2 - log(sqrt(2*pi) * sigma));
```

---

In a previous version of this answer I wrote:

```
sigma = sqrt(sum(stats.resid .^ 2) / stats.dfe);
```

This is not correct, since it gives the square root of the unbiased estimator of the residual variance, not the MLE of sigma.

---

In response to the poster's comment: The standard deviation can be computed this way because the MLE of the standard deviation of a normal distribution is the root-mean-square of deviations. A nice derivation for the variance of a simple normal distribution model (a special case of the GLM) can be found at [statlect](http://www.statlect.com/normal_distribution_maximum_likelihood.htm). Maximum likelihood estimation is invariant under transformations, and therefore the MLE of the standard deviation is just the square root of the MLE of the variance. For the full GLM the derivation is slightly more complicated, but with the same result: Instead of using the deviation from the mean one uses the deviations from the linear fit, and these are stored by `glmfit` in `stats.resid`.

You can check the correctness of the computation numerically in Matlab like this. Implement a function that computes the (negative) log likelihood for specific parameters b and sigma, and then use an optimization function to minimize it (find the MLE estimate of the parameters):

```
function mleGLM

X=[1;2;3;4];
y=[1.1;2.2;3.5;4.9];

[param, fval, exitflag] = fminunc(@nll, [0 0 1], optimset('TolX', 1e-10));

    function nll = nll(param)
        b = param(1 : end - 1);
        sigma = param(end);
        resid = X * b(2 : end) + b(1) - y;
        nll = - sum(-0.5 * (resid / sigma) .^ 2 - log(sqrt(2*pi) * sigma));
    end
end
```

You will find that `param(3)`, which corresponds to `sigma`, is identical (up to numerical error) to the result of the formula above; and `param(1 : 2)` correspond to the `b` output of `glmfit`.

Comment: Please ignore my ignorance, but why I can compute sigma like that?

Comment: @SibbsGambling, I extended my answer, does this help?

Comment: YES, that helps a lot. I will look into that, thanks a lot!